# KVM permission denied on qcow2 disk over NFS

Tags: centos, permissions, kvm-virtualization, nfs

CentOS 6.3 running libvirt 0.10, trying to access/run a vm using  a qcow2 on a Windows Server 2008 NFS mount.  I tried nfsvers-3 when mounting but not luck, I get permission denied, presumably because the qemu user doesn't have rw access to the remote NFS server. I can read and write to the mount as root fine.

Comment: did you add `execution` privilege via `sudo chmod +x /your/nfs` on the directory where your NFS volume is mounted?

Comment: Yes it is RWX across the board on the remote machine's mount folder.

Comment: Seems this is a Windows NFS server issue.

Answer (score 1):

windows unix services are tricky to set up properly, and aren't recommended for production use at all. Having said that, here's how I have it set up on a 2008r2 box - this share hoss ISO files I use to install KVM  VMs

[image: Share properties]

[image: Share properties 1]